# How to delete the dynamic fields via selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

In my Test application I have  different usernames/buttons,which are deletable .

I want to automate the delete functionality

How shall i approach ?

A. Shall I create new user name  and delete same user name everytime  ?(For every Run )
If yes ,how would   I know new X-path for created  username ?>

B.Shall I delete existing user name for every run  (If yes,what happens if i want to rerun the test cases ?)

Pl advice me

Thanks,
R

Comment: Html would help understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on where its located in the html you could search for it using xpath.

```
//a[text()='username']
```